# update single record with results from multiple case query

Tags: case

Found related type solutions, but nothing to match my need;
I want to update an existing table record (fields pu_cnt, pu_ot, pu_ltc etc.) with the result from the query (pu_cnt, pu_ot, pu_ltc etc.) etc.
Here's my query:

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN vuWO_CHC_ALL.status IN('C','D','H','F') THEN 1 END) AS 
    pu_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(vuWO_CHC_ALL.actpu_delay_code,1) LIKE '' THEN 1 END) AS 
    pu_ot,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(vuWO_CHC_ALL.actpu_delay_code,1) LIKE 'C' THEN 1 END) 
    AS pu_ltc,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(vuWO_CHC_ALL.actpu_delay_code,1) LIKE 'U' THEN 1 END) 
    AS pu_ltu,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN vuWO_CHC_ALL.status IN('D','H','F') THEN 1 END) AS del_cnt,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(vuWO_CHC_ALL.actdel_delay_code,1) LIKE '' THEN 1 END) AS 
   del_ot,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(vuWO_CHC_ALL.actdel_delay_code,1) LIKE 'C' THEN 1 END) 
   AS del_ltc,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(vuWO_CHC_ALL.actdel_delay_code,1) LIKE 'U' THEN 1 END) 
   AS del_ltu
   FROM vuWO_CHC_ALL WHERE
   RTRIM(vuWO_CHC_ALL.SHIPPER) LIKE @pVendor AND
   RTRIM(vuWO_CHC_ALL.ORIG) LIKE @pOrigin AND
   RTRIM(vuWO_CHC_ALL.Dest) LIKE @pDestin
```

..

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using @variables.